Modify vertex for polygon in QGIS Python script
For a given polygon, I'd like to modify the vertex, some of them should be deleted and some of them should be updated with new coordinates. And I know exactly the index for the related vertex.
The QgsGeometry does not have methods like update or something else. I found the QgsVectorLayerEditUtils can be used. But it need the layer as argument:

QgsVectorLayerEditUtils(layer).moveVertexV2(newLocation,atFeatureId, atVertex)

While in my script, I can not access the layer object but only the geometry object. So for a updated vertex at vertexId x I try to insert a new vertex before the x and put the x to vertex_id_be_deleted list.
for index, _ in enumerate(geometry.vertices()):
  vertex = geometry.vertexAt(index);
  #test if this vertex should be deleted? Or updated and calculate the new location
  
  if should_updated:
    geometry.insertVertex(new_p.x(),new_p.y(),index)
    vertex_id_list_to_deletion.append(index)
  if should_deleted:
    vertex_id_list_to_deletion.append(index)


vertex_id_be_deleted.reverse()
  for vertex_id in vertex_id_be_deleted:
      geometry.deleteVertex(vertex_id)

However during the first loop, the vertex id(index) will changed, so the second loop may delete un-expected vertex.
Any solution to modify geometry vertex directly?

Would iterating twice work? First update than delete.

I may ignore some details in my question, I updated that.

Why you use second loop? If you testing vetrex dynamically, i guess, you can delete it in first loop

@Dezmonder: Sound right, I make a little change for my previous code, it works now.

Finally, I tried insert a new vertex and delete the current vertex, and it works for now:
new_geometry=QgsGeometry(geometry)
for index, _ in enumerate(geometry.vertices()):
  vertex = geometry.vertexAt(index);
  #test if this vertex should be deleted? Or updated and calculate the new location
  
  if should_updated:
    geometry.insertVertex(new_p.x(),new_p.y(),index)
    new_geometry.deleteVertex(next_vertex_index)
  if should_deleted:
    vertex_id_list_to_deletion.append(index)


vertex_id_be_deleted.reverse()
  for vertex_id in vertex_id_be_deleted:
      geometry.deleteVertex(vertex_id)

